# Videos on Wordpress page loading on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: wordpress, video, elementor, videodisplay

I have added a couple of videos to a WordPress blog post. When I am loading the page on a desktop, everything seems to be functioning exactly as it should. When I load the same page on my Android phone in Chrome, it always fails to load 1 video. When I refresh, there will always be one video that doesn't show up. Which video this is, changes with every refresh. I also checked on my partner's iPhone with Safari. There, even fewer videos are showing as they should.

All the videos have been added using the elementor plugin and are saved and loaded from my host server. I can't figure out how to solve this problem because I can't figure out what causes this issue to begin with. I have googled a bit and only found solutions regarding auto-play. I haven't set my videos to autoplay, so this doesn't explain why I have problems.

The blog post can be found [here](https://www.unfoldmyworld.com/wilderness-canoeing-first-surf-lesson/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

99% it's because of incorrect video codec. I would suggest to re-format videos with [Handlebrake](https://handbrake.fr/) prior to uploading. This tool helped me multiple times with problems like this.